# Problemas com o PhoneGap

Tags: apache-cordova

Descobri este PhoneGap a pouco tempo, mas hoje eu obtive vontade de conhecê-lo. Bom, como dizia no site, eu precisava baixar o NodeJS e executar um comando no CMD para que este instalasse o PhoneGap.

Após isto, precisava criar uma pasta para que o PhoneGap o cadastrasse como um aplicativo a ser desenvolvido.

O site dizia que eu precisava executar isto na pasta do projeto:

```putty
phonegap run android
```

Mas ao executar o comando, retornou o seguinte erro em minha janela do CMD:

```putty
E:\Outros\PhoneGap\fenix>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[phonegap] missing library cordova/android/3.3.0
[phonegap] downloading https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-androi
.git;a=snapshot;h=3.3.0;sf=tgz...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\Users\iXaDe\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and ad
ed to your path.
    at C:\Users\iXaDe\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:
7:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

**EDIT**

Após instalar o **ant**, o phonegap ainda acusa erro:

```putty
  E:\Outros\PhoneGap\fenix>phonegap run android
  [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
  [phonegap] using the local environment
  [phonegap] adding the Android platform...
  [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.
   C:\Users\iXaDe\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                       throw e;
                      ^
   Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you
   have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command
   -line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
       at C:\Users\iXaDe\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:8
   0:29
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo executar o comando, mesmo que eu já tivesse um aplicativo desenvolvido, não estou conseguindo executá-lo.

Comment: Posta o link do tutorial que estava seguindo na sua pergunta.

Comment: A propósito, duas leituras importantes para um melhor aproveitamento do Stack Overflow em Português: http://br.stackoverflow.com/about e http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective

Comment: O erro diz que você não tem a última versão do Android SDK. Que versão você tem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O teu erro:

> Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.

Que se traduz em:

> Erro: Por favor instale o Android versão 19 (a última versão do SDK do Android). Certifique-se também de que tem a última versão das ferramentas do Android instaladas também. Execute "android" a partir da linha de comandos para instalar/atualizar quaisquer SDKs ou ferramentas em falta.

Diz-nos que o teu problema pode ser um de dois:

1. Tens o que é preciso instalado mas não tens os caminhos configurados;
2. Não tens o que é preciso instalado e precisas instalar.

## Lidar com os caminhos

Tens duas formas para adicionar o SDK do Android ao `path` do windows. 
Para efeitos de clareza, vamos assumir que tens a instalação em:

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools
```

1. Linha de Comandos

   A partir da linha de comandos podes executar:

   ```
   set path=%path%;C:\android-sdk-windows\tools;
   ```
2. Ambiente Gráfico

   Podes aceder à janela de configuração da variáveis de ambiente e editar para adicionar o caminho desejado:

   1. Aceder a:

      > "O Meu computador" → "Propriedades" → "Avançadas" → "Variáveis de Ambiente";
   2. Escolher e editar a variável `path`:

      [image: Captura de Tela]
   3. No final adicionar o caminho:

      ```
      C:\ android-sdk-windows\tools;
      ```

      Especial atenção à utilização do `;` para separar dos caminhos existentes.

      [image: Captura de Tela]

## Instalar o que falta

Se não tens o Android SDK, no mínimo a versão solicitada que é a 19, deverás instalar antes de procederes à verificação dos caminhos.

[**SDK Tools | Android Developers**](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html)

---

<sup>E é isto para lidar com o erro que está a ter. Outros erros poderão surgir após esse, mas já é outro assunto que merece outra pergunta.</sup>

Comment: Mesmo atualizando, ainda recebi erro: `Error executing "adb devices": 'adb' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.`

Comment: @iXaDe Sugiro que abras uma pergunta a perguntar como resolver esse erro. Adiciona a informação relevante e os passos que estás a realizar que causam o erro. Ps: Ainda bem que entretanto este problema ficou ultrapassado.