# Problemas com a utilização do Phonegap

Tags: android, windows, apache-cordova

Estou tentando usar o Phonegap pela primeira vez, mas estou tendo problemas.

Eu já tinha o NodeJS instalado, consegui instalar o Phonegap com `npm install phonegap` sem problemas. Depois, como sugere [esta página](http://phonegap.com/install/), criei um app com `phonegap create myapp` sem problemas, mas ao tentar rodar com `phonegap run android`obtive o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Users\MEU_USUÁRIO\Desktop\myapp>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

C:\Users\MEU_USUÁRIO\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^ Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add ed to your path.
    at C:\Users\MEU_USUÁRIO\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\lib\check_reqs.js: 47:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12) { [Error: C:\Users\MEU_USUÁRIO\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\create.bat: Com mand failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }    [error] C:\Users\MEU_USUÁRIO\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\create.bat: Co mmand failed with exit code 8
```

Pesquisando na web, há várias soluções diferentes, aparentemente cada solução funciona para um caso diferente. Tentei `npm install cordova`, configurei `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME`, `Path`, instalei [o tal de Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) e configurei `ANT_HOME` e nada disse me serviu, continuo com o mesmo erro.

A solução apresentada [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2295/7261) não me serviu. Não sei mais o que fazer.

Vale lembrar que o AndroidSDK + Eclipse já estava instalado e funcionado antes mesmo de eu instalar o Phonegap. Estou usando Windows 7.

Comment: Este erro aí é em relação ao Ant_Home que na verdade deve-se chamar ANT_DIR e também adicioná-lo ao PATH do windows. Para ter certeza, execute o comando `ant` no cmd e veja se ele executa

Comment: @Caputo Executar `ant` no cmd retorna `Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!\nBuild failed`

Comment: E trocou ANT_HOME por ANT_DIR?

Comment: @Caputo Agora troquei, o erro mudou. Agora ele diz que a versão "mais nova" do SDK, a 19, não está instalada. Fui conferir aqui e eu tenho a versão 20. Vou tentar instalar a 19.

Comment: Se não me falhe a memória, cada versão do SDK que vai ser utilizada precisa ser instalada separada, mas você pode definir a versão do SDK no arquivo JSON da sua APP do phonegap ou no manifest do android

Comment: @Caputo Brigadão! Agora tá funcionando direitinho =)

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema com dois passos:

- Mudando `ANT_PATH` para `ANT_DIR` como sugeriu nosso amigo @Caputo.
- Instalando a versão 19 do SDK (antes eu só tinha a 20).

Obrigado ao @Caputo pela força!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver o segundo erro, o correto não é simplesmente instalar a versão 19, funciona, sim, mas se desejar utilizar uma versão mais antiga ou mais nova do SDK basta colocar as seguintes linhas no arquivo config.xml, no meu caso configurado para android 2.3 (SDK 10).

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="10" />
```